# Implementing EventTarget on custom objects

Tags: google-closure, dart

Using Closure Library, you can give any object the ability to dispatch events extending [`goog.events.EventTarget`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_events_EventTarget.html). Is this currently possible using Dart libraries?

I imagine it would look like this:

```javascript
#import('dart:html');

class Foo implements EventTarget {
  Events get on() {
    // ???
  }
}

main() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();

  // Subscribe to the event.
  foo.on['bar'].add((Event event) => print('bar!'));

  // Dispatch the event.
  foo.on['bar'].dispatch(new Event('bar'));
}
```

Am I on the right track?

**Edit** Thanks to Lars Tackmann, a working draft is here: http://try.dartlang.org/s/f6wk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways, one method could be to use **typedef**'s to define a generic handler function:

```dart
class Event {
   final String type;
   Event(this.type);
}

typedef EventHandler(Event event);

interface EventTarget {
  Map<String,EventHandler> get on();
  void dispatch(Event event);
}

class Foo implements EventTarget {
  Map<String, EventHandler> _handlers;
  Foo() {
    _handlers = new Map();
  } 

  Map<String, EventHandler> get on() {
    return _handlers;
  }

  dispatch(Event event) {
     EventHandler handler = _handlers[event.type];
     handler(event);
  }
}

main() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();

  foo.on['bar'] = (Event event) => print('handling event ${event.type}');

  foo.dispatch(new Event('bar'));
}
```

I made a DartBoard snippet for you [here](http://try.dartlang.org/s/r5gk) to play around with.

You might want to experiment with making **EventTarget** into a base class, unless of cause it messes up your inheritance strategy (in which case a event bus you can inject with a factory might be a better fit).

Comment: Woah. It looks a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks for the complete example and dartboard snippet. :) The event bus pattern is new to me but I'll read more about it.

Comment: Your DartBoard snippet allows a single listener to be registered (see: http://try.dartlang.org/s/8rsk). Here is a version that supports multiple: http://try.dartlang.org/s/LBkk

Answer (score 2):

I think you are, but I favor a more robust event model for internal objects than the one used to wrap DOM events in Dart.  The one I use models more after the .net event model, and allows passing of both the source object, and an EventArgs class (or sub-class) carrying data related to the event.

https://github.com/LUCA-Studios-LLC/LUCA-UI-Framework-for-Dart/blob/master/core/FrameworkEvent.dart

looks like:

```dart
FrameworkEvent<EventArgs> myEvent = new FrameworkEvent<EventArgs>();

//here subscribing using custom operator override "+"    
var handler = myEvent + (Dynamic source, EventArgs args) {
 //do stuff when the event fires here
};

//fire the event
myEvent.invoke(this, new EventArgs());

//unsubscribe using operator override "-"
myEvent - handler; //unsubscribe from the event here
```

Comment: Right now I'm favoring an interface that stay as close as possible to `dart:html`'s events interface. But your approach is interesting and I want to play around with this.